# How to get lines in matplotlib plot to continue past x-axis limit (python)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

My goal is to plot lines that represent certain days of the year. Note: I *do not* want to use a package like date time -- I am just trying to do this with the data points as integer values. So in the plot below, the event at y=3 lasts between day 123 to 189 and event at y=2 lasts between days 214 and 365.

Where I run into problems is with event at y=1, which should go from day 205 to 22 (that's what's in the `data` dataframe). However, the plot does not know that I am plotting days of the year (obviously) and so it stretches from day 0 to 205, which is wrong. Instead, it should start at 205, stretch to the right and then end at the value of 22. I've hand drawn in blue what it should look like.

[example figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnJmk.png)

Help?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[3,123,189],[2,214,365],[1,205,22]]), columns=['name','start','end'])
plt.hlines(data['name'],data['start'],data['end'],linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Event')
```

Comment: The simplest thing is to make two events 1: [1, 205, 365] and [1, 1, 22].  If you are going to automate this, you need only check if start > end.

Comment: I have 1000s of rows of data, so if you could give some pseudo code that would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[3,123,189],[2,214,365],[1,205,22]]), columns=['name','start','end'])

endstart = (data.index[data['start'] > data['end']].tolist())
startend = ([i for i in range(len(data)) if i not in endstart])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot startend
ax.hlines(data['name'][startend],data['start'][startend],data['end'][startend],linewidth=1)
# plot endstart
ax.hlines(data['name'][endstart],data['start'][endstart],365,linewidth=1)
ax.hlines(data['name'][endstart],0,data['end'][endstart],linewidth=1)

ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Event')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I just had to make the following change and then the code worked: startend = ([i for i in (data.index) if i not in endstart])